# Maximum value of largest side

Tags: quadrilateral

If we have a quadrilateral with integral and distinct sides and second largest side is 10 then the value of largest side is?
And, we can solve it by saying that other two sides will be 9 and 8 respectively {because the other two sides are distinct and their sum is greater than 10 so their maximum values are 9 and 8} and largest side is smaller than the sum of remaining sides hence largest side < 27 
Hence, 26 
But, if we join the vertices of side 9 and 8 then with same reasoning we can say that third side's maximum value is 16 and now we have to find the largest side of the remaining triangle. And we can say that it must be smaller than 10 +16=26 hence, 25 is the answer now which is correct and why?

Comment: First, get the question right.  You are looking for the maximum length of the longest side, but the question asks to determine the length of the longest side.  We cannot do that as there are a number of possibilities.

Comment: That is why it is asked to find the maximum length

Comment: My point is that  the word maximum does not appear in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If three sides are $8,9,10$ in that order there is no reason for the diagonal from the end of the $8$ to the other end of the $9$ to have integral length.  It could be a length just less than $17$, allowing the fourth side to be $26$

Comment: Right, thanks for the answer I didn't considered that